# how to assign a value to element of a String array?

Tags: arduino

the code below ia an array included few of Strings, which can be set 0 ot 1 by button's status. and each String (array element) control a led ON/OFF.

I have got:  `Varray[3] = 1 and Varray[3] = dbcd;`

my question is how to get: `dbcd = 1 ;`

I have many buttons which controlled many leds, I like to have: button (A)  pressed and relatively set a marker let's say `ledA = 1;` and then control led_a by: `if(ledA ==1){digitalWrite (led_a, HIGH); }`

need help please.

Thanks

Summer

```
int abcd = 0;
int bbcd = 0;
int cbcd = 0;
int dbcd = 0;
int ebcd = 0;
int i = 0;
int k = 3;
int j = 3;
int m = 2;

int Varray[] = {abcd, bbcd, cbcd, dbcd, ebcd,};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    if (i == k) {
      Varray[i] = 1;
    }
    else {
      Varray[i] = 0;
    }
  for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    Serial.print("L44 - Varray[i] = ");
    Serial.println( Varray[i]);
    delay(200);
  }
  mainO();
}


#include <stdio.h>

void mainO()
{
  char arr[5][10] = {"abcd", "bbcd", "cbcd", "dbcd", "ebcd"};
  printf("String array Elements are:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    Serial.print("L69 - Varray["); Serial.print(i); Serial.print("] =");
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }
  // return 0;
}
```

I have tested the code on Arduino IDE, and fail to get: dbcd = 1, that's what I like to have.

Comment: You might want to elaborate what are you trying to do. To me it looks like you want array of references or something, don't know what's with that c-strings..

Comment: Thank you KIIV. I have many buttons which controlled many leds, I like to have: button pressed and relatively set a marker let's say ledA = 1; and then control led_a by: if(ledA ==1){digitalWrite (led_a, HIGH); } . I'll put this above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you want, but let's make some organized code so everything is more clear and go step by step:

You say you have buttons and leds, let's then define the pins where they are connected. Let's use arrays so changing the number of leds and buttons is easy.

```
const int BUTTONS[4] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
const int LEDS[4] = {6, 7, 8, 9};
```

Then from your question looks like you want to read the buttons and save the value in an array. Then use this array values to turn on or off the leds. So let's define an array to store this values.

```
bool values[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
```

In the setup we just need to define buttons as inputs and leds as outputs.

```
void setup() {
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    pinMode(BUTTONS[i], INPUT);
    pinMode(LEDS[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}
```

We can make a function to read buttons and update the array `values`

```
void read_buttons() {
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    values[i] = digitalRead(BUTTONS[i]);
  }
}
```

Similarly a function that controls the leds based on the values of the array `values`

```
void control_leds() {
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    digitalWrite(LEDS[i], values[i]);
  }
}
```

The main loop just reads buttons and controls leds
Since mechanical buttons might bounce, we can use a simple delay as debouncing.

```
void loop() {
  read_buttons();
  control_leds();
  delay(100);  // for button debouncing
}
```

That's it. You should try to organize your code like this. Simple steps, comments and descriptive names for functions and variables.

You can use this code as a template and incorporate more funtionalities as needed. My advice is that you keep the `loop` function simple. If you need to do something specific (eg: send the values to PC via serial) don't do it in the loop function. Make a function `transmit_data` and just call it from the loop function.

Comment: Thank you Sembei Norimaki for your detail help, I'll improve the code format. Yes, your code solved the button-led control question. I still wonder if it is possible to get: dbcd = 1; in c++ as in my design. Because I'd like to use 'dbcd = 1' in other situation also.  If it is not possible, I may have to manually set that.

Comment: In your code `dbcd` is a variable. If you want to assign 1 to this variable just do `dbcd = 1;` I don't know what dbcd does in your code, the name of the variable is not descriptive and there are no comments explaining what is the purpose of this variable, but as an integer you can of course assign integer values to it

Comment: Thanks. I mean assign the: 'dbcd = 1; ' by code not manually. just like: ' if (i == k) {
      Varray[i] = 1;    } ' and because of the : 'Varray[3] = 1' and  'Varray[3] = dbcd', (k=3) so how to assign 'dbcd = 1 '?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. Do you mean assign dbcd = 1 if a certain button is pressed? I don't know what are your Varrays and dbcd. In my code your read the button values into the array `values`. You can do `if (values[3] == HIGH) {dbcd = 1;}` if that's what you are asking

Comment: Thanks. the 'for loop' in my post set that 'if (i == k) , set Varray[k] = 1', and others 'Varray[i] =0;' because of the 'Varry[3] = dbcd, (if set k=3)', is it possible let code set 'dbcd=1'? like  'printf("%s\n", arr[i]) = 1'? I can do like your code 'if (values[3] == HIGH) {dbcd = 1;' but if the Varray has 20 elements, and each time need set one of =1 others =0, its a job. sorry I don't know how to use code-tag here.

Comment: make a loop `for (int i=0; i<20; i++)` which iterates the 20 elements. then check if the current element is k  and set the array to 1 `if(i==k) {Varray[i] = 1;}`  otherwise set it to 0  `else {Varray[i] = 0;}`  but again, no idea what your dbcd things are. I think you should rewrite your code getting rid of all this obscure variables and make a clean code where it's clear what you try to achieve

Comment: Thanks. the Varray [] = {abcd, bbcd, cbcd, dbcd, ebcd  ......}, the dbcd is the content of Varray[3].